# devise_token_auth and rails 5.2.0 Compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devise-token-auth

Hi i'm using devise_token_auth with `rails 5.1.6` .When i updated my `rails` version to `5.2.1` so i can use `acts_as_favoritor 2.1.0`, i got the error in my `elasticbeanstalk` environment log:

```
Column `tokens` of type ActiveRecord::Type::Json does not support `serialize` feature. Usually it means that you are trying to use `serialize`
```

is there any specific version of devise_token_auth that i can use with `rails 5.2.1` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this means your database does not support a JSON datatype.

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html
- https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: This is an answer. The answer says that the problem is occurring because the OP's database does not support a JSON datatype, implying that a solution could be to add JSON support to the database or remove the JSON dependency in the code. If you feel that this is wrong or not useful, the correct action is to downvote it, not flag it as Not An Answer.

Comment: I didn't do anything @RobertColumbia

Comment: @ElFadelAnas I didn't say you did. Someone reported Ig Norand's answer as Not An Answer (NAA), and I wanted to clarify that it was an answer and didn't deserve summary deletion.

Comment: @RobertColumbia sorry for the misunderstood